# How can I achieve swipe animation in react-native?

Tags: react-native, swipe, react-native-ios

How can I achieve swipe of one by one with animation in react-native package. Kindly refer to the attached thread for example.

https://github.com/chitezh/react-native-swiper-animated/issues/42#issue-488651377

Here it will be in any shape (round, rectangle, Square shape)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this library can be helpful for you:
https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel

It allows you to create different types of cards and animations to navigate through them.

Comment: I also need a scroll animation while swiping one card to another card

Comment: @sejn in the documentation to this library there is a page about custom interpolations. It has the `scrollInterpolator` prop which should help you. Here it is:
https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/CUSTOM_INTERPOLATIONS.md#prop-scrollinterpolator

Answer (score 0):

Try with this library, with this you can scroll swiping one card to another card

```
react-native-swiper
```

for more information [check this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper)

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: It not help for my above requirement